# Set the minimum for HTML input type time

Tags: html, datetime, input, time, min

I am trying to set the minumum for the time input type.
But it won't let me set it to a value for the minutes, like: 09:30.
Then it sets to 09:00.
This is my HTML:

```
<input type="time" min="09:30" max="17:30" step="300">
```

Thanks!

Comment: In what way does “it” (some browser?) prevent you from setting (somehow? which way?) the value to 09:30?

Answer (score 0):

It will actually work, with a validation error should you try to submit the form with a time earlier than 09:30.

It would seem browsers don't start the minutes stepping from 30 though, probably because users may need to enter any value between 0 and 59 for the valid range of hours.

Answer (score 0):

correct values format: `min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59"`

First group of 2 digits represents hours, second group of 2 digits represent minutes and third group of 2 digits represents seconds.

The "step" option represents the increment/decrement of the time value in seconds.

Comment: Your answer has been flagged low-quality. I guess you wanted to tell the OP, that he needs to use "HH:mm:ss" format. Maybe you can improve your answer?

Comment: @Fildor This was flagged as low quality because the answer is short, nothing else. It is a valid answer... whether it is good or bad one is not a concern of the low quality post review.

Comment: @Lundin I asked him to "improve his answer" because it was flagged low quality. I said nothing about why it was flagged. Maybe my comment was not so clear, sorry 'bout that.

Comment: first group of 2 digits represents hours, second group of 2 digits represent minutes and third group of 2 digits represents seconds. The "step" option represents the increment/decrement of the time value in seconds. Is it clear now @Fildor ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using FireFox, input type time isn't supported.
Your code works in Chrome.